# Revert accidental `dpkg --clear-selections`

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg

I wanted to "purge" all packages that were "removed" only. After skimming through the manpage of `dpkg`, I thought the `--clear-selections` parameter would do the trick. So stupid me typed it in with `sudo`, and afterwards I checked the selection states again and was shocked.

**`dpkg` has selected all (non-vital) installed packages to get uninstalled!**

This was of course my fault, but definitely not intended. So, how do I revert this?

I still have the terminal window open where I ran `dpkg --get-selections | grep deinstall` both *before* (85 packages) and *after* (2614 packages) the accidental command.

What I need now is to subtract the first (old) deinstall list from the second (current) one and mark all those packages as wanted again. Setting them to `manual` will not be good though, as that would affect hundreds of libraries which make no sense if installed without their applications. So we have to set it to `auto` and then I probably have to manually find out the top level packages to be selected as `manual`. Or can something help me there?

Info: I have two separate text files, one containing the first `--get-selections` output, one the second. They contain only lines with the syntax:

```
package-name         deinstall
```

where `package-name` is, well, the actual package name, and the space in between is an undefined number of tabs.

**Update:** I just found the output of `dpkg --get-selections` from before the accident without any `grep` filtering! Only two packages were installed after that, I can fix them manually later.

Please help me to restore my previous package selections!

Comment: Is `/var/lib/apt/extended_states` still intact? If yes, back it up!

Comment: @Nephente After having remembered that I still have the full old output of `dpkg --get-selections`, I could solve the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To set **all** packages currently selected to `deinstall` back to `install`, you run the following two commands:

```
sudo dpkg --get-selections | awk '/deinstall/ {printf "%s\t%s\n",$1,"install"}' > packages
sudo dpkg --set-selections < packages
```

The first command finds all packages marked with `deinstall` and writes a list of packages like this

```
package-name         install
```

The second command corrects the packages.

---

If the full output of `dpkg --get-selections` from *before* the accident is given, you can simply restore all selections with the command

```
sudo dpkg --set-selections < packages
```

where `packages` is the name of the file holding the old output.

Comment: First, I need to restore the previous state, where 85 packages were correctly set to deinstall. So I need the difference of the two files where I stored both outputs before and after the bad command and set only them back again. Second, what will it set those to? Is it the same as `apt-mark auto` or `apt-mark manual` or something entirely different?

Comment: You are a life saver. Thank you for prepping this awk and procedure!