# How to purge previously only removed packages?

Tags: apt, package-management, uninstall, dpkg, purge

I have a list of packages on my system, that were installed and removed again, but not purged, i.e. there are still a lot of conffiles etc. laying around.

The output of `dpkg --get-selections | grep deinstall` lists about 85 different packages which I don't need and want to be purged entirely.

So my short question, which I decided to finally ask after experimenting around has lead to [this problem](https://askubuntu.com/q/687272/367990), is:

*How do I completely **purge** previously installed packages that are already removed?*

Reinstalling and then purging is not an option, of course.

Comment: "Reinstalling and then purging is not an option, of course." LoL **;)**

Comment: @DevRobot I don't see the joke. It would be possible and pretty surely work, but don't have the time to download and install tons of packages just to get rid of them...

Comment: I know - it's the _of course_ - relates **:)**

Comment: I think you can do `sudo apt-get purge [package]` **after** you have removed them. I just tried it and it worked.

Comment: I often use `aptitude` for that -- pressing `_` on the line `Not installed packages` will mark all of these packages for configuration file removal. Not an answer because aptitude is likely going away.

Comment: This is not a duplicate. The referenced article solves the problem for a single package. This is about cleaning up multiple packages without manually fiddling around.

Comment: Here is an easy answer to this question which is marked as a duplicate but is not one: `aptitude purge ?config-files` of course you will need to have installed `aptitude`

Answer (score 58, accepted):

I just found the following command which worked:

```
sudo apt-get purge $(dpkg -l | grep '^rc' | awk '{print $2}')
```

Comment: Hmm, I suspect this will hit the command line argument length limit if you have 50000 uninstalled package. waltinator's solution below does not. Not that I see that ever happening.

Comment: `dpkg -l | awk '/^rc/{print $2}' | sudo xargs apt-get purge` You're welcome.

Comment: @Tobia that last part should be `sudo xargs apt -y purge`, to avoid it attempting to ask for confirmation in a subshell.

Comment: Or just using dpkg: `dpkg -l | awk '/^rc/ {print $2}' | sudo xargs dpkg -P`

Comment: There really should be a standard command in apt for doing this.

Comment: Is there some nicer method now by 2021?

Answer (score 28):

`dpkg  --get-selections | grep deinstall` produces a list of package names with the word "`deinstall`":

```
$ dpkg  --get-selections | grep deinstall
account-plugin-windows-live         deinstall
debarchiver                         deinstall
flashplugin-installer               deinstall
    ...
```

By asking `awk` to print only the first field we get:

```
$ dpkg --get-selections | awk '$2 == "deinstall" {print $1}'
account-plugin-windows-live
debarchiver
flashplugin-installer
    ...
```

Now that we have the list of packages, `xargs` will let us feed the list of packages to a command (or commands, if the list is long enough):

```
dpkg --get-selections | awk '$2 == "deinstall" {print $1}' | xargs sudo apt-get purge --dry-run
```

When you are happy with the simulated results, replace `--dry-run` with `-y` in the `apt-get` command.

Relevant documentation:

```
man dpkg awk xargs apt-get
```

Comment: On my system , Ubuntu 15.04,  I had to  add the `-y` option to `apt-get` to stop the command from aborting before the packages were removed.

Comment: For those that don't awk, you can use `grep deinstall | cut -f1` instead of `awk '$2 == "deinstall" {print $1}'`. Using `cut` may actually flow better with this style write up.

Comment: Very nice answer. A simpler alternative would be to verify that `aptitude search '~c'` emits the list of packages you want to remove and then you just do `sudo aptitude purge '~c'` to remove all those packages. Also try `aptitude search '~o'` to list obsolete packages (that is, packages that are no longer supported by any repository you have).

Answer (score 4):

My fifty cents, a simple oneliner:

**First test** with

```
dpkg --get-selections | awk '$2=="deinstall" {system("sudo apt-get --dry-run purge "$1)}'
```

and bye bye

```
dpkg --get-selections | awk '$2=="deinstall" {system("sudo apt-get -y purge "$1)}'
```

---

Example

```
% dpkg --get-selections | grep deinstall
nginx-common                    deinstall

% dpkg --get-selections | awk '$2=="deinstall" {system("sudo apt-get -y purge "$1)}'

% dpkg --get-selections | grep deinstall
[no output]
```

Comment: Or `sudo apt-get --dry-run purge $(dpkg --get-selections | awk '$2=="deinstall" { print($1) }')` to avoid spawning a new shell for every package installed. Replace `--dry-run` with `-y` once you feel comfortable about the operation.

Answer (score 3):

If you just want to purge the whole list, you can use this command; it will perform a dry run, in case essential packages are going to be removed, which you probably don't want to happen:

```
dpkg --get-selections | sed -n 's/\tdeinstall$//p' | xargs sudo apt-get --dry-run purge
```

If no essential package is going to be removed, it's safe to run the actual command:

```
dpkg --get-selections | sed -n 's/\tdeinstall$//p' | xargs sudo apt-get --yes purge
```

- `sed -n 's/\tdeinstall$//p'`: prints only lines in `stdin` where a tabulation followed by a `deinstall` string could be removed from the end of the line; this has the effect of printing only the lines containing a tabulation followed by a `deinstall` string at the end of the line without the actual tabulation followed by the `deinstall` string at the end of the line
- `xargs sudo apt-get --yes purge`: passes each line in `stdin` as an argument to `sudo apt-get --yes purge`

Answer (score 1):

I asked this myself a couple of days ago. Came up with

```
apt-get purge $(dpkg -l | awk 'BEGIN{ORS=" "} /^rc/{ print $2}')
```

The removed but not purged packages appear in the output of `dpkg -l` with `rc` at the beginning. `awk` picks out the second column aka the name of the package and prints them space-separated.

Comment: Even easier: `aptitude purge ?config-files`