# Why would installed packages have status "Remove"?

Tags: apt, dpkg, aptitude

While doing other maintenance tasks I noticed that `dpkg -l` listed about 90 packages with  status `ri` instead of expected `ii`.

I maintain packages solely with `apt` and `aptitude` and I haven't forced any packages but I regulary do `apt install --no-install-recommends ...` to avoid getting unneeded packages. I also try to carefully maintain the "automatically installed" flags and I have 2914 packages with status "automatically installed" (`aptitude search '~i~M'`) and 422 packages with status "manually installed" (`aptitude search '~i!~M'`).

**What could be the reason for packages to have status `Remove` + `Inst` (`ri`) in `dpkg -l` listing when I haven't requested those packages to be removed?** It seemed that the packages with this status were packages that I actually want to keep in the system. Could e.g. `sudo apt dist-upgrade` cause this without me noticing?

(I know that I can reinstall those packages with `apt install --reinstall package-name` to get status back to `ii`. I also often purge removed packages and `aptitude search '~c'` lists no packages.)

**Additional details from another system with the same issue:**

```
$ sudo apt dist-upgrade && sudo apt autoremove && dpkg -l | grep ^ri | wc -l
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages have been kept back:
  virtualbox-6.0
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 3 not upgraded.
171
```

So `dist-upgrade` nor `autoremove` do not touch the 171 packages with `ri` status.

Example package with `ri` status:

```
$ dpkg -l ca-certificates-java
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name                                            Version                      Architecture                 Description
+++-===============================================-============================-============================-===================================================================================================
ri  ca-certificates-java                            20160321ubuntu1              all                          Common CA certificates (JKS keystore)
```

and additional info for the same package:

```
$ aptitude show ca-certificates-java
Package: ca-certificates-java            
State: installed
Automatically installed: no
Multi-Arch: foreign
Version: ...

$ aptitude why ca-certificates-java 
i   default-jre-headless   Depends openjdk-8-jre-headless
iBA openjdk-8-jre-headless Depends ca-certificates-java  

$ apt-mark showhold
virtualbox-6.0
```

**Additional info after reading about possible causes:**

As explained in answer https://askubuntu.com/a/802612/50254 the status of these packages can be fixed to match currently installed packages by running (note that the line feed after `IFS` is not a typo but this command requires setting `IFS` to single linefeed):

```
export IFS='
'
for i in $(dpkg -l |egrep '^[a-z]i.*' |awk '{print $2" install"}') ; do echo $i|dpkg --set-selections  ; done
unset IFS
```

**The reason/cause for this problem is still unknown.** The `ri` status is supposed to mean that `dselect` (old debian package manager nowadays completely replaced by `apt`) has used to mark package to be removed from the system and if you actually want to apply those selection states you can run `apt-get dselect-upgrade`. See `man dpkg` and section "INFORMATION ABOUT PACKAGES" for more information.

The `apt install --reinstall package-name` is also okay but it will do more than the minimum change to system to fix the problem.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but it sound to me that the packages marked with `ri` could have been a dependent of another package that was removed but they weren't removed as maybe the `--autoremove` switch for `apt` wasn't used.  But I don't recommend using `--autoremove` as you may remove other needed packages.  I wish that part of package management was perfect, but it's not.  I have accidentally killed systems because an app set them all for autoremove.

Comment: That was a good suggestion but it wasn't the cause. I added info how neither `dist-upgrade` nor `autoremove` do anything to these packages.

Comment: Hmmmmm, yeah, sorry, I am out of suggestions on this one.  +1 and hopefully someone else has stumbled across this.  Running `dpkg -l | grep -w "ri"` yields nothing on my system, but `dpkg -l | grep -w "rc"` does, but thats for config and a completely different scenario.  I hope you find an answer!

Comment: I have been looking a little deeper into your situation and while I am really not finding any solid answers for what is actually causing this, maybe some clues to be able to remedy might be found in https://askubuntu.com/posts/1352232/edit , https://askubuntu.com/a/165961/231142 and https://askubuntu.com/a/166254/231142

Comment: @Terrance: It seems that the packages marked `ri` match this list: `dpkg --get-selections | awk '$2 == "deinstall" {print $1}'`. So the question is what process could accidentally mark `deinstall` for `dselect` when I don't use `dselect` for anything?

Comment: Oops, I just realized that in my above comment the first link is one that was in my buffer.  My bad.  Let me see if I can find the correct link there. It had some decent info in it.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know what exactly is causing it.  I guess you can look through the logs in `/var/log/dpkg.log` or maybe something like `journalctl -xe`.  I really wish I was experiencing the same issue as it would really help to have a second pair of eyes.  Another link that I did find was where the `--clear-selections` was ran and caused something similar.  It is hard to say if this might have been ran either.  https://askubuntu.com/questions/687272/revert-accidental-dpkg-clear-selections?rq=1

Comment: Yeah, I did read about `dpkg --clear-selections`, too, but I definitely haven't run that. And *I'll not run that after reading what it does*. I did also find that `deinstall` is historically used to signal `dpkg` by `dselect` that a package should be removed. However, I just checked and I don't even have `dselect` installed so that shouldn't be setting incorrect flags. Very interesting problem indeed. My current guess would be that VirtualBox package has executed some wrong commands because both these systems have VirtualBox installed and this problem seems to be pretty rare in general.

Comment: I also checked `journalctl` and it doesn't mention the problematic package during the last 1.5 years I've logs available. The system was installed about 11 months earlier so the error must have happened at that time or whatever causes this doesn't not log to `journalctl` at all.

Answer (score 2):

<sub>disclaimer: i'm not a pro when it comes to distributions, so these are just my guesses by putting 1 and 1 multiple times together.</sub>

#### prologue

on an older Ubuntu machine i have one package with status `ri`, which is `libllvm5.0` (and a bunch of other normal `ii`-packages like `libllvm4.0` and `libllvm6.0`). the packages <= `libllvm5.0` are marked as manually installed but `libllvm6.0` is marked as automatically installed.
so my guess would be, that it was a dependency and got obsolete ether by upgrading or removing the dependent package.

#### explanation

going through your arguments/conditions one by one:

- *i only use `--no-install-recommends`*:
  well, needed dependencies are installed nevertheless, else the program wouldn't work.
- *`autoremove` does nothing to these packages*:
  well, kind of... i'm pretty sure all the `ri`-packages left alone by `autoremove` are marked as **manually** installed, although you have never installed it "separately". this is because after an initial setup a very few (if any?) packages are marked as automatically installed due to the fact that it isn't really possible to determine what packages **you** would have installed intentionally because this would vary from user to user. (so... a kind of "you have manually installed your OS".)
- *could `sudo apt dist-upgrade` cause this?:*
  no and yes... `sudo apt dist-upgrade` on itself does not cause this, but with upgrading the whole system it is much more likely, that a bunch of (initially installed) packages will get obsolete.

to wrap up **THE REASON**: my guess would be that that these packages were installed by the initial setup, therefore marked as manually installed and then got obsolete by upgrading some packages or the whole distribution. and because they are marked as manually installed, they aren't touched by `autoremove`.

Comment: This sounds reasonable explanation. All the packages having status `ri` also have status `Automatically installed: no` when queried with `aptitude show packagename`. However, I'd expect *all* manually installed packages to always stay in `ii` status instead of getting marked for removal with `ri` status.

Comment: @MikkoRantalainen: why do you expect this? or differently phrased: why should the package management be dumbed down? **||** the `r` just shows the **"desired"** status on **behalf of dpkg**, which only indicates, that there is no more package **via dpkg** installed, which depends on the package in question. - as the "manually installed" flag overrides these suggestions, because no package management can guess if sideloaded programs or some of your scripts still depend on this package, it won't do anything to this package.

Comment: so the result is: if a package was installed as a dependency resp. is marked as "automatically installed", it also gets automatically uninstalled (via `autoremove` and depending on your setting for "recommendations" and "suggestions") as soon as no other package depends on it. - is a package marked as "manually installed", the `r` is just a suggestion from dpkg considering its packages, but you have to decide ("manually" again), what to do with it. so if you do nothing, the system stays as it is to not break anything.

Comment: and if you know what you are doing, and you installed the package on purpose because you needed it for a script or similar but this is no longer the case, the `r` indicates that you can safely remove it (not considering other dependencies outside of dpkg)... and if it shows `ii` you can still simply mark this package as "automatically installed" and the package manager takes care of the rest... no need to be bothered with dependencies or monitor this package regularly.

Comment: As I explained in the question, the packages with `ri` status did not get removed with `apt dist-upgrade`  nor `apt autoremove`. What's the purpose of the `r` if it doesn't even affect those commands?

Comment: @MikkoRantalainen: why should they get removed with any of these commands, since you have also confirmed they have the status "manually installed"? it would still break something else outside of dpkg depending on these packages. - as long as they are marked as "**manually** installed", they won't be **automatically** unistalled. **||** the `r` indicates that no other package managed via dpkg depends on it, and thus dpkg **suggests** to remove it. if it is marked as "automatically installed", this suggestion is followed, if not then not.

Comment: I have packets that are marked as automatically installed and have `ri` status. Is it safe to assume that the reason those are not uninstalled by `dist-upgrade` or `autoremove` is some other package has the package as `Recommends` or `Suggests`? That would then prevent the system from automatically removing those packages even if nothing depends on them?

Comment: @MikkoRantalainen: at first i would have a look at the settings: `apt-config dump | grep -E -i -e 'APT::(Install|AutoRemove).*'` and even `apt-config dump | grep -E -i -e 'APT::Never.*'` could be interesting in some cases. but i guess https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/544878/93768 should answer your question.

Comment: Thanks! So `r` in `ri` means that the package *could* be uninstalled because nothing is depending on it but `apt` will not uninstall it if it's Recommended by some package that's still installed for any reason (included chain of Recommended packages from one installed package).